# DP - Counting coin change

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

The problem requires to count number of coin changes for a particular cost.

For example, if I have coin values of `50, 20, 10, 5, 1`, I can form costs of:

5 => (5), (11111), which are 2 ways.

10 => (10), (5, 5), (5, 11111), (11111, 11111), which are 4 ways.

Here is my function. It is returning wrong results begging from cost of 10 (returns 9 ways while the actual number of ways is only 4)

```
int dp[10000];
int coins[] = { 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 };
int rec(int n)
{
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  if (dp[n] != -1) return dp[n];
  int cnt = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    if (coins[i] <= n) cnt += rec(n - coins[i]);
  return dp[n] = cnt;
}
```

How can I fix this function to give the correct number of ways? Is this algorithm correct even? see the complete code and its output [here](http://ideone.com/9rHCQ)

**NOTE**: my problem is not with `dp` array initialization. I am using `memset` to initialize it to `-1` each time before calling `rec`.

Comment: What is the problem exactly (what do you _want_ to get, and what do you _actually_ get)?

Comment: What's the result your code gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) and (1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1) is different way in you algorithm, you should keep it decreasing.

```
int dp[10000][5];  // dp[20][2] means, if the biggest coin is coins[2],
                   // how much ways for 20 ?
int coins[] = { 1, 5, 10, 20, 50 }; // here
int rec(int n, int m)
{
  int cnt = 0;
  int i;
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  //if (m == 0) return 1;
  if (dp[n][m] != -1) return dp[n][m];
  for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
    if (coins[i] <= n) cnt += rec(n - coins[i], i);
  return dp[n][m] = cnt;
}

int main()
{
        memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
        printf("%d\n", rec(10, 4));
}
```

Comment: Why did you call it with `m = 4` ?

Comment: He exchanged the order. He made the coins go from smallest to highest, and the for loop from 0 to m, so its the same as mine, just differently formatted...

Comment: @Lai it is not different. I am sorry I forgot to indicate so. The algorithm requires to count ***distinct*** ways.

Answer (score 1):

The result is wrong since you never make sure that your algorithm starts with the 5 coin. (5,11111) is just as valid in your code as (1, 5, 1111), but this is the same result. Your result should be wrong from 6 and higher, not 10 and higher.

To fix this you can do like a cutoff in your function rec():

```
int rec(int n, int cutoff)
{
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  if (dp[n] != -1) return dp[n];
  int cnt = 0;
  for (int i = cutoff; i < 5; i++)
    if (coins[i] <= n) cnt += rec(n - coins[i], i);
  return dp[n] = cnt;
}
```

Should do it.

Edit: you will have to take care of your dp[] array, since it does not care about this cutoff, but this in general is the fault you are running into. You could comment that line, and check if this works.

Comment: So how to call it with n = 10 for example?

Comment: The first call will have to be with rec(10, 0). I have edited that your dp[] array will screw up that algorithm, so just to make sure the idea works, you should comment the line if(dp[n]!=-1)...

Comment: Sould I make `dp` two dimensional to use cutoff? It doesn't work when taking off the comment

Comment: Yes, that would be the fix for that. The second element should show the maximum number allowed. Would be something like Lai wrote, I just wanted to show where the error was coming from.

Answer (score 1):

One remark: Your initialization

```
memset(dp, -1, sizeof dp);
```

is not really safe. `memset` initializes every *byte* of a memory space (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/.). For this particular case you are lucky and the representation of `int(-1)` is (probably) the same of four times `unsigned char(-1)`.

I would suggest using `std::fill` ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/ ).